# About the remark of the proof that every operator on non-zero finite dimensional complex vector space has an eigenvalue in Linear Algebra Done Right

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question

In the 2nd Edition of Linear algebra Done Right, theorem 5.10 (Every operator on a finite-dimensional, nonzero, complex vector space has an eigenvalue), the author writes as a side note:

> Compare the simple proof of this theorem given here with the standard
> proof using determinants. With the standard proof, first the difficult
> concept of determinants must be defined, then an operator
> with 0 determinant must be shown to be not invertible, then
> the characteristic polynomial needs to be defined, and by the time the
> proof of this theorem is reached, no insight remains about why it is
> true.

However, the approach given by the author does not seem to give me any more insight for why this theorem is true than the standard proof using determinants. Both proofs seem to just find some trick to transform this into a problem about roots of polynomials, in order to apply FTA. Am i missing some intuition about this

Here's the proof for reference:
[image]

Comment: It would help if you include the proof in question.

Comment: @user3716267 added

Comment: I agree with your sentiment. Also, complaining about "oh for the standard proof one *needs* to define the determinant. one *needs* to define the characteristic polynomial, one *needs* to show that $0$ determinant means the operator is not invertible" sounds a bit odd for a linear algebra text. Those are among the most powerful concepts of linear algebra, and one should be happy about any opportunity to define them, and show how useful they are.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg : No, you don't need to define the characteristic polynomial. He didn't define the characteristic polynomial. Dimension was invoked in order to conclude some combination of vectors would have to be $0$. Nothing else.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts: Sorry, maybe my comment was phrased badly. I know that in the approach of the book one does not need to define the characteristic polynomial, determinant etc.; I just disagree with the claim in the book's comment that that is a good thing. The book says: "Here, look at this proof without determinants, characteristic polynomial ..." I say: But in a linear algebra course, it is a *good thing* to define determinants, characteristic polynomials etc., and then use them in proofs. Ultimately it gives deeper insight and allows to tackle more problems than any ad hoc proof.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg : Fair enough. I have my own objections with regard to this approach, especially the use of the phrase "... Done Right" in the title of a book. The arrogance in that makes me cringe. Avoiding a determinant erases a little too much history for my taste. The determinant came out of finding a general way to solve linear equations, and I certainly don't think it was "done wrong."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was thinking about the same a few months ago, I think Axler's point is that the proof using determinants needs a theoretical framework that's rather more difficult to develop because you need to define the entities that he mentions in his comment of the proof (determinant and characteristic polynomial ) and show that an operator with $0$ determinant is not invertible. That could be rather painful for a pure mathematician trying to write an elegant text (this is my opinion). Now, if you look at his proof carefully you see that it is rather based on linear independence, a pretty basic concept that he defines at the beginning of the text. Following his approach also has the benefit that you can define the determinant later on as a product of eigenvalues, which to me makes the concept very intuitive.